# AngularJS - href ng-click - event bubbling

Tags: angularjs, event-handling

In the following example:

```html
<div class="sub-list" ng-repeat="item in list.subItems">
  <a class="list-row" href="#">
    <span class="list-cell name">item.name</span>
    <span class="list-cell dt">item.dt</span>
    <span class="list-cell summary">
      <span class="sub-list-item" ng-click="page.updateSubStatus(item); $event.stopPropagation();">Click</span>
    </span>
    <span class="list-cell list-row-link-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

When I click on the span href action is also invoked due to event bubbling. 
I even used `$event.stopPropagation` but still the problem persists.

I cannot remove href in `<a>` tag, I need the href operation as well. On click of the item it needs to navigate to respective url but on click of span "Click" it needs to invoke my controller function.

Can some one help me how to handle the click on span tag above but not the href event.

Working Sample:

```html
<div class="sub-list" ng-repeat="item in list.subItems">
  <a class="list-row" href="#">
    <span class="list-cell name">item.name</span>
    <span class="list-cell dt">item.dt</span>
    <span class="list-cell summary">
      <span class="sub-list-item" ng-click="page.updateSubStatus(item); $event.preventDefault();">Click</span>
    </span>
    <span class="list-cell list-row-link-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: remove href="http://google.com/" from <a >

Comment: add ng-click="page.updateSubStatus(item); $event.stopPropagation();" to <a> and remove href="#"

Comment: No I cannot do that, I need the href operation as well.
On click of the item it needs to navigate but on click of span "Click" it needs to invoke my controller function. @hadiJZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you have to use Angular and jQuery event handling. See below code snippet. And working https://plnkr.co/edit/seF391qx3OcUubT8MeO7?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('demoController', function($scope, $anchorScroll) {

  $scope.list = {};
  $scope.list.subItems = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  $scope.page = {};
  $scope.page.updateSubStatus = function(item) {
    alert(item);
  }
})

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a span.sub-list-item').on('click', function(event){
    console.log(event)
    event.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="demoController">
  <div class="sub-list" ng-repeat="item in list.subItems" on-finish-render>
    <a class="list-row" href="www.google.com" >
      <span class="list-cell name">item.name</span>
      <span class="list-cell dt">item.dt</span>
      <span class="list-cell summary">
      <span class="sub-list-item" ng-click="page.updateSubStatus(item)" on-click="disableClick()">Click</span>
      </span>
      <span class="list-cell list-row-link-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, event.preventDefault() worked..!!