# ng-click of child element div (Stop Propagation)

Tags: angularjs

I have following html markup

```
<div class="myDiv docTypeDesc">
     <div data-ng-click="setDocumentType(type)"> {{type.name}}
          <i data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" data-ng-show ="type.description && type.description != ''"  class="icon-info-sign icon-large hand hintModal bottomRight" style="float: right;padding: 2px 7px 0 0;">
               <div class="hintModal_container animated fadeInBottom"> 
                     {{ type.description }}
               </div>
           </i>
      </div>
```

I dont want the click of 'i' to propagate to parent data-ng-click. I tried the above thing and also tried returning false from a scope function but no good, as this scope function of i's click is not getting called and the call goes to parent's ng-click

Comment: Create a directive as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544741/how-can-i-make-an-angularjs-directive-to-stoppropagation

Comment: can you try with both event.preventDefault() and event. stopPropagation()

Comment: Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400229/angularjs-href-ng-click-event-bubbling/36403882#36403882. Only **$event.preventDefault();** will work.

Comment: maybe your `i` element is too small or has transparency, so you're actually clicking on the element below/behind.

Comment: The scope function of i's click is not even getting called... Apologies I missed to tell you this.

Comment: Don't wrap a div inside an `i` tag.. Might be the cause of it since it won't have a decent clickarea.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz that is required for the plugin which i am using to show the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the i's click to eventually do something.  Set that up.  What if you put an actual method call on the i like handleEvent($event);

```
scope.handleEvent = function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Seems the same, I'm just curious.

Comment: handleEvent is not getting called @Jason